# Return nested entities with child entities with a Linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm trying to return an entity that has a nested entity itself through Linq expressions through a Web Api. I've come up with this so far:
return db.Tracks.Include(x => x.LapTimes);

Which returns the following:

```
    {  
   "Id":2,
   "Name":"Nurburgring",
   "Length":20800,
   "Country":"Germany",
   "LapTimes":[  
      {  
         "Id":2,
         "Time":6.48,
         "CarId":2,
         "Car":null,
         "TrackId":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":5,
         "Time":6.52,
         "CarId":3,
         "Car":null,
         "TrackId":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":6,
         "Time":6.55,
         "CarId":4,
         "Car":null,
         "TrackId":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":7,
         "Time":6.57,
         "CarId":5,
         "Car":null,
         "TrackId":2
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem is that I can't for my life figure out how to include the right Car entity based on foreign-key "CarId" inside the LapTime entity through a Linq expression.

**My Entities**

```
public Car()
{
    Laptimes = new List<Lap>();
}

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Lap> Laptimes { get; set; }


}
public class Lap
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CarId")]
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TrackId")]
    public Track Track { get; set; }

}
public class Track
{
    public Track()
    {
        LapTimes = new List<Lap>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Lap> LapTimes { get; set; }   

}
```

Comment: You have to *include* it as well, for instance (if EF6) `.Include(x => x.LapTimes.Select(y => y.Car))`

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!